# exit function when number of records in 0

Tags: vb.net, listview, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I am applying a search filter on my listview `(sSQL)`. I want to cancel the action when it turns out no records were found, otherwise the Listview is empty and I can't undo the filter.

```
Private Sub LoadStandardListview(Optional ByVal sFilter As String = "")

        Try
            Dim sSQL As String
            Dim sSubStr As String
            Dim strs As String
            If sFilter = "" Then
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief WHERE ([Document Type] Is Not Null) AND ([DISnummer] Is Not Null) AND ([XPostnummer] Is Not Null) AND ([Last Accessed] Is Not Null) ORDER BY Id DESC"
            Else
                sSubStr = " AND [Document Name] LIKE '%" + sFilter + "%' "
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief WHERE ([Document Type] Is Not Null) AND ([DISnummer] Is Not Null) AND ([XPostnummer] Is Not Null) AND ([Last Accessed] Is Not Null)" + sSubStr + "ORDER BY Id DESC"
            End If
            strs = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Archief"
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strs, con)
            Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim dis As String
            Dim docImage As VariantType
            Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
            dr.Read()
            Dim recordCount As Long
            recordCount = cmd2.ExecuteScalar

            ListView1.BeginUpdate()
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            While dr.Read
            If dr("Document Type").ToString = "PDF" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pdf" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
            ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "DOC" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "doc" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 3)
            ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "PPT" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "ppt" Then
                docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 2)
            End If

            dis = dr("Last Accessed").Substring(0, dr("Last Accessed").IndexOf(" "))
            items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", dr("Document Name").ToString, dr("DISnummer"), dr("XPostnummer"), dis, dr("Id").ToString, dr("Document Location").ToString}, docImage))
        End While
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)
        ListView1.EndUpdate()
            sNumRec = items.Count
            If sFilter <> "" Then
                ToolStripTextBox3.Text = sNumRec + " Documents"
            Else
                ToolStripTextBox3.Text = recordCount.ToString + " Documents"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Is there a way I can cancel the actions when no records are found and populate the listview again with all records?

Comment: Where are the `Using...End Using` blocks? Don't use a DataReader for all that processing. The connection must be open when there is an active DataReader. Fill a DataTable and close the connection. To answer your question...`If dt.Rows.Count <1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Mary  You want me close the connection after the listview has been filled?

Comment: No, I want you to load a DataTable and then close and dispose the connection. You fill the listview from the values in the DataTable. Connections are precious objects. They should be opened as late as possible and closed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sSQL As String
            Dim sSubStr As String
            If sFilter = "" Then
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief ORDER BY Id DESC"
            Else
                sSubStr = "WHERE [Document Name] LIKE '%" + sFilter + "%' "
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief " + sSubStr + " ORDER BY Id DESC"
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
            Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim dis As String
                Dim docImage As VariantType
                Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

                If dr.HasRows() Then

                    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
                    ListView1.Items.Clear()

                    While dr.Read
                        If dr("Document Type").ToString = "PDF" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pdf" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "doc" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "docx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 3)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "ppt" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pptx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 2)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "xls" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "xlsx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 4)
                        End If

                        dis = dr("Last Accessed").Substring(0, dr("Last Accessed").IndexOf(" "))
                        items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", dr("Document Name").ToString, dr("DISnummer").ToString, dr("XPostnummer").ToString, dis, dr("Id").ToString, dr("Document Location").ToString}, docImage))

                    End While
                    ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)
                    ListView1.EndUpdate()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Nothing was found.",, Title)
                End If
                dr.Close()

            End Using
```

I changed my code a little. I put

```
Using dr as New OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows() Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you use the value of `cmd2.ExecuteScalar` which is the `recordCount`? Try this

```
If recordCount > 0 Then
   While dr.Read
         ...
   End While
   dr.Close()
Else
   `Refill listview with no filter`
End If
```

Comment: I use cmd2.ExecuteScalar to count the total datatable because I didn't trust the total count in filling the Listview

Comment: Check if the value from `ExecuteScalar` is greater than 0, if yes, then proceed to `reader.Read` then exit sub or show prompt if equals to 0.